# ionic version 6 local notification content security policy error while running ionic serve

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, localnotification

I have finished installing local notification from ionic components using angular but I'm receiving cannot get/

in the inspect element console :

Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:8100/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Here is the link and tutorial i used for installing local notification : *https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications*

Comment: Try to remove the platform android/ios.

Comment: can you please explais sir , because i need the platform for android and ios to build this app , thank you

Comment: It means Remove platform and add it again.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib ok sir ill try thank you

Answer (score 3):

I also had a lot of problems with this error! It can come from several places from what I understand. In my case, the message in the chrome console was the following:

Refused to load the image because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

and the WEB page simply displayed the message: Cannot Get /

there were still errors in my code but my IDE doesn't display them when I run "ionic serve". **To solve the problem I did a build ("ionic build") and fixed the displayed problems.**
I hope this answer will help :)

Comment: Stuck in this for a while LOL, great answer would suggest making it shorter to focus the attention on the bold part.